# Why am I getting this exception System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException? What am I missing?

Tags: c#

I am try to make one combobox dependent on what is selected in another combobox.

I am successful in connecting to the database and populating the comboboxes but I get the following exception System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException. the exception happens at:
    int id = categoris[comboBoxCategory.SelectedIndex].id;

```
    private void comboBoxCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object 
sender,EventArgs e)
        {
             comboBoxMovie.Items.Clear();
             **int id = categoris[comboBoxCategory.SelectedIndex].id;**
            foreach (string name in GetMovieById(id))
            {
                this.comboBoxMovie.Items.Add(name);
            }
        }
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I have included the full code below just to help out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ComboBox_Test
{
     public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
        List<Movie> movies = new List<Movie>();
        List<Category> categoris = new List<Category>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new MyConnection().GetConnection();
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmdCate = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tb_categories", conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmdCate.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                comboBoxCategory.Items.Add(dr["cate_name"]);
                categoris.Add(new Category(){
                id = ((int)dr["cate_id"]),
                cate_name = dr["cate_name"] as string
            });
            }
            conn.Close();
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmdMovie = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tb_movies", conn);
            SqlDataReader dr1 = cmdMovie.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr1.Read())
            {
                movies.Add(new Movie()
                {
                    id = ((int)dr1["id"]),
                    movie_name = dr1["movie_name"] as string,
                    cate_id = ((int)dr1["cate_id"])
                });
            }
            conn.Close();
         }
        private string[] GetMovieById(int id)
        {
            return movies.Where(line=>line.cate_id==id).Select(l=> l.movie_name).ToArray();
        }

         private void comboBoxCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBoxMovie.Items.Clear();
            int id = categoris[comboBoxCategory.SelectedIndex].id;
            foreach (string name in GetMovieById(id))
        {
            this.comboBoxMovie.Items.Add(name);
        }
        }
        [Serializable]
        class Category
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string cate_name { get; set; }
        }
        class Movie
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string movie_name { get; set; }
            public int cate_id { get; set; }

        }

     }

    }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your highlighted line. How many items are in that collection when your breakpoint activates? You might have an off-by-one error.

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? it seems that comboBoxCategory.SelectedIndex is out of the range of the categories array. I'm not spotting the error here, but knowing the selectedIndex is a start for your debugging

Comment: Have you tried to put a breakpoint on that line and see that the value of 'categoris' and 'comboBoxCategory.SelectedIndex' is?

Answer (score 0):

While I will admit that I haven't attempted to build your code, if the exception is being thrown from `int id = categoris[comboBoxCategory.SelectedIndex].id;` as you state in your question, the only explanations I can see is that either A) object `categoris` doesn't have as many items in it as `comboBoxCategory` does, or B) object `comboBoxCategory` doesn't have an item actually selected.  If scenario B) is the case, `comboBoxCategory.SelectedIndex` will evaluate as -1 and calling `categoris[-1]` will definitely throw the ArgumentOutOfRangeException.
I have my money on B) but only testing on your end will let you know for sure.  If you put a breakpoint on the line in question, can you determine what `comboBoxCategory.SelectedIndex` evaluates to?  If it's something other than -1, can you determine how many items are in `categoris`?